# 403 forbidden instead of successful authorization! Why?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

I am writing a `Spring-MVC` application using `Spring Boot` and `Hibernate`. The application has a `User` who has the role of `Admin` and `Customer`. I decided to add `Spring Security JWT` and did everything right. Now that I have everything ready, I want to get a `TOKEN`, I log in successfully, but in return I get *403 Forbidden*. What have I done wrong? Did you configure *configs* incorrectly or did the *roles* incorrectly?

Configs:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // Fields
    //
    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    //


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().disable().csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }
}
```

Controller:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthenticationController {

    // Fields
    //
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    private final UserService userService;
    //


    // GET-Methods
    //
    //
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> login(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequestDTO requestDto) {
        try {
            String login = requestDto.getLogin();
            authenticationManager
                    .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, requestDto.getPassword()));

            User user = userService.findByLogin(login);

            String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(login, user.getRole());

            Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
            response.put("login", login);
            response.put("token", token);

            return ResponseEntity.ok(response);

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid login or password");
        }
    }
}
```

User class:

```java
@Getter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    // Fields
    //
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    private String login;

    private String password;

    private String mail;

    private boolean isDeleted;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
}
```

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    // Fields
    //
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Value("${jwt.token.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Value("${jwt.token.expired}")
    private Long validityInMilliSeconds;
    //


    // METHODS
    //
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }


    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        secret = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret.getBytes());
    }

    /**
     * Генерируем ТОКЕН
     *
     * @param login
     * @param role
     * @return ТОКЕН
     */
    public String createToken(String login, Role role) {

        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(login);
        claims.put("roles", getRoleName(role));

        Date now = new Date();
        Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + validityInMilliSeconds);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(validity)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret)
                .compact();
    }


    public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {
        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(getLogin(token));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "", userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }


    public String getLogin(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }


    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token);

            if (claims.getBody().getExpiration().before(new Date())) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new JwtAuthenticationException("JWT token is expired or invalid");
        }
    }


    public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String bearerToken = req.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer_")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }


    private String getRoleName(Role role) {

        String roleName = role.name();

        return roleName;
    }
}
```

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtTokenFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                         ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken((HttpServletRequest) request);

        if (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            Authentication auth = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token);

            if (auth != null) {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
@Slf4j
public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userService.findByLogin(login);

        JwtUser jwtUser = JwtUserFactory.create(user);
        log.info("IN loadUserByUsername - user with login: {} successfully loaded", login);
        return jwtUser;
    }
}
```

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class JwtUser implements UserDetails {

    // Fields
    //
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String lastName;

    private String login;

    private String password;

    private String mail;

    private boolean isDeleted;

    private Role role;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role));
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

P.S. I will not throw all the code for `JWT` from the project here, but skip only the most important thing.

[image]

LOGS:

```java
2020-08-10 16:36:27.343  INFO 7556 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 64 ms
2020-08-10 16:36:28.454  INFO 7556 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] r.c.security.JwtUserDetailsService       : IN loadUserByUsername - user with login: art123 successfully loaded
```

Comment: your jwt has roles, can you permit path based on the role present in jwt

Comment: with roles problem is the same